# Prove orthogonality

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**Let $ABC$ be any triangle . Two squares $BAEP$ and $CAFR$ are constructed externally to $ABC$.Let $M$ be the midpoint og $BC$.
Show that $AM$ is orthogonal to $EF$.**

I have no idea how to prove its perpendicular.

Maybe both triangles $ABC$ and $EAF$ share this property.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the proof is, but it would suffice to show that angles FEA + EAG = 90, where G would be the point of intersection if you extended AM into EF. Additionally, angle EAF = (ABC + BCA) and BAC = (FEA + AFE) which I feel might be critical for the proof.

Comment: I am using the same,didn't prove useful yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Since the question is posed without much context, here's a solution using vectors. (I myself would prefer an Euclidean-geometrical approach.)

Since $$\begin{aligned}\vec{AM}&=\frac12(\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}),\\ \vec{EF}&=\vec{AF}-\vec{AE}\end{aligned}$$ it suffices to show that 
$$(\vec{AB}+\vec{AC})(\vec{AF}-\vec{AE})=0.\tag{1}$$
But the LHS of (1) is
$$ \vec{AB}\cdot \vec{AF}+\vec{AC}\cdot \vec{AF}-\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{AE}-\vec{AC}\cdot\vec{AE}.$$
Since $AC\perp AF$ and $AB\perp AE$, we only need to show
$$\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{AF}=\vec{AC}\cdot\vec{AE}.\tag{2}$$
But (2) is clear since $AB=AE$, $AC=AF$, and $\angle BAF=\angle EAC$.

---

Euclidean style:
[image]

Let $A^\prime$ be the reflection of $A$ about $M$, so $AC\parallel BA^\prime$. It follows that $$\angle ABA^\prime=\angle EAF=180^\circ-\angle BAC.$$
Thus, $\triangle AEF=\triangle ABA^\prime$. So $\angle AEF=\angle BAA^\prime$. Simple angle chasing should imply that $AA^\prime\perp EF$.

Note that we proved even more that $EF=2AM$.